# find the occurence of all vowels in a sentence

Tags: java

I am writing code that find all vowels `'a' 'i' 'u' 'e' 'o'` in a sentence that I write and count them.

The code will ignore the case of the vowel(upper or lower). Since I don't know how to make the vowel count case insensitive, I just convert all text to lower case and count the vowels. I wonder if there is another way to do it without converting all uppercase letter text to lowercase and count the vowel. Thank you all for the input, I really appreciate it. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        //create vowel array
        char[] vowel = new char[]{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        int[] countVowel = new int[5];
        String yourSentence;
        //print message
        System.out.print("Enter your word here:");
        //set word entered as next input
        yourSentence = input.nextLine();
        String actualSentence = yourSentence.toLowerCase();

        for (int j = 0; j < actualSentence.length(); j++) 
        {
            char c =actualSentence.charAt(j);
            if(c=='a')
                countVowel[0]++;
            else if(c=='e')
                countVowel[1]++;
            else if(c=='i')
                countVowel[2]++;
            else if(c=='o')
                countVowel[3]++;
            else if(c=='u')
                countVowel[4]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <countVowel.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Count of vowel " + vowel[i] + "=" + countVowel[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably better off using a switch statement, because it's very readable and can easily be optimised by the compiler

```
yourSentence = input.nextLine();
// String actualSentence = yourSentence.toLowerCase();

for (int j = 0; j < yourSentence.length(); j++) 
{
    switch( yourSentence.charAt( j ) ) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            ++countVowel[0];
            break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            ++countVowel[1];
            break;
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            ++countVowel[2];
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            ++countVowel[3];
            break;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            ++countVowel[4];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know we can set 2 cases to do one counter like you did above. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

you change you input `yourSentence` to upper case

```
String newResult = changeCase.toUpperCase();
```

and then ask if the last sentence contain any of the charecter you wanted.

this is completely not what you wanted to do.

i'll give you an example solution but there are many more you can do.

```
String newResult = changeCase.toUpperCase();

if(newResult.contains("A") ||newResult.contains("E") || newResult.contains("O") || newResult.contains("I") || newResult.contains("U"))
   // Your code
```

now, if you want to count it, you can use `indexOf` and delete occurrences:

```
while(newResult.indexOf("U") > -1)){
  counter++
  newResult.replaceFirst("U", "!");

}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, somehow when I write the same format like your have for while loop; I got error

Comment: here is the error String newResult = changeCase.toUpperCase();
  //print message
  System.out.printf("%s\n", actualWord);
  int counter;
  //conditional
  if(newResult.contains("A") || newResult.contains("E") || newResult.contains("I")
  || newResult.contains("O") || newResult.contains("U"))
  {
   System.out.println( newResult );
   
   while(newResult.indexOf("A") > -1; counter++)
   {
    newResult.replaceFirst("A","!");
    System.out.print("found vowel \"a\" appear ");
    System.out.println(newResult.indexOf('a'));
   }

Comment: the error is related to counter++. I declared the counter, put ; after counter++, just general idea about counter but somehow it still get the error

Comment: @NumbNuts it's a bit hard for me to understand that from the comment, can you edit your question and add the error? after that write a comment here so i'll know.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I look at other people questions and I get the vowel count right. I will reupload my code and re-edit my problem